# What is the error in this TRIGGER?

Tags: mysql, trigger

The MySQL version I'm using is 5.1.46.
The query is

```
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `movimentacao_before_del_tr` BEFORE DELETE ON `movimentacao`
  FOR EACH ROW
 IF (OLD.stMov IN ("E", "C", "R")) THEN
    INSERT INTO `controle` (
      `tabela`,
      `data`,
      `hora`,
      `registro`
    ) VALUES (
      MD5("movimentacao"),
      OLD.dtEmissao,
      CURTIME(),
      CONCAT_WS("|",
        OLD.idMovimentacao,
        OLD.idEcf,
        OLD.numFabricacao,
        OLD.CCF,
        OLD.stMov,
        OLD.tpNota,
        OLD.modoMov,
        OLD.dtMovimentacao,
        OLD.dtEmissao,
        OLD.hrEmissao,
        OLD.numNF,
        OLD.idPessoa,
        OLD.cpfCnpj,
        OLD.rgIe,
        OLD.nomePessoa,
        OLD.codcidade,
        OLD.uf,
        OLD.cidade,
        OLD.bairro,
        OLD.logradouro,
        OLD.numero,
        OLD.complemento,
        OLD.cep,
        OLD.totalBruto,
        OLD.valAcrecimo,
        OLD.valDesconto,
        OLD.valOutrasDespesas,
        OLD.valFrete,
        OLD.valSeguro,
        OLD.bcICMS,
        OLD.valICMS,
        OLD.bcICMSST,
        OLD.valICMSST,
        OLD.valPIS,
        OLD.valCOFINS,
        OLD.totalLiquido,
        OLD.idNatOp,
        OLD.idAidf,
        OLD.especie,
        OLD.serie,
        OLD.docProprio,
        OLD.chaveNFe,
        OLD.motivoCancelamento,
        OLD.hrMovimentacao,
        OLD.IdTransportador,
        OLD.modFrete,
        OLD.qtdeVolumes,
        OLD.especieVolumes,
        OLD.marcaVolumes,
        OLD.pesoL,
        OLD.pesoB,
        OLD.infAdFisco,
        OLD.infCpl,
        OLD.enderecoTransp,
        OLD.cidadeTransp,
        OLD.UfTransp,
        OLD.finNFe,
        OLD.placaVeicTransp,
        OLD.ufVeicTrans,
        OLD.RNTC,
        OLD.idOperador,
        OLD.chk,
        OLD.hash,
        OLD.hash2
      )
    );
  END IF;
```

The returned is `#1064 - Você tem um erro de sintaxe no seu SQL próximo a '' na linha 79`. Translation: You have a MySQL syntax error near to '' on line 79.

The Workbench show an erro at the last line: `syntax error, unexpected END_OF_INPUT, expecting ';'`

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the delimiter to accept semicolons properly while creating the trigger

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `movimentacao_before_del_tr` BEFORE DELETE ON `movimentacao`
  FOR EACH ROW
 IF (OLD.stMov IN ("E", "C", "R")) THEN
    INSERT INTO `controle` (
      `tabela`,
      `data`,
      `hora`,
      `registro`
    ) VALUES (
      MD5("movimentacao"),
      OLD.dtEmissao,
      CURTIME(),
      CONCAT_WS("|",
        OLD.idMovimentacao,
        OLD.idEcf,
        OLD.numFabricacao,
        OLD.CCF,
        OLD.stMov,
        OLD.tpNota,
        OLD.modoMov,
        OLD.dtMovimentacao,
        OLD.dtEmissao,
        OLD.hrEmissao,
        OLD.numNF,
        OLD.idPessoa,
        OLD.cpfCnpj,
        OLD.rgIe,
        OLD.nomePessoa,
        OLD.codcidade,
        OLD.uf,
        OLD.cidade,
        OLD.bairro,
        OLD.logradouro,
        OLD.numero,
        OLD.complemento,
        OLD.cep,
        OLD.totalBruto,
        OLD.valAcrecimo,
        OLD.valDesconto,
        OLD.valOutrasDespesas,
        OLD.valFrete,
        OLD.valSeguro,
        OLD.bcICMS,
        OLD.valICMS,
        OLD.bcICMSST,
        OLD.valICMSST,
        OLD.valPIS,
        OLD.valCOFINS,
        OLD.totalLiquido,
        OLD.idNatOp,
        OLD.idAidf,
        OLD.especie,
        OLD.serie,
        OLD.docProprio,
        OLD.chaveNFe,
        OLD.motivoCancelamento,
        OLD.hrMovimentacao,
        OLD.IdTransportador,
        OLD.modFrete,
        OLD.qtdeVolumes,
        OLD.especieVolumes,
        OLD.marcaVolumes,
        OLD.pesoL,
        OLD.pesoB,
        OLD.infAdFisco,
        OLD.infCpl,
        OLD.enderecoTransp,
        OLD.cidadeTransp,
        OLD.UfTransp,
        OLD.finNFe,
        OLD.placaVeicTransp,
        OLD.ufVeicTrans,
        OLD.RNTC,
        OLD.idOperador,
        OLD.chk,
        OLD.hash,
        OLD.hash2
      )
    );
  END IF $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Give it a Try !!!